How to introduce custom parametrization in @ConditionalOn.. annotation in Spring Boot
I have to add handling of new version of external API for one of clients. So we had beans with @Component annotation which had additional annotation:
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = SOME_PROPERTY_NAME, havingValue = "val1")

Thus in many cases I created new Components with condition "havingValue = 'val2'", but some beans do not require changes, so they should be common.
After search here and other places the only working solution I found is to use
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${some.property}' == 'val1' or '${some.property}' == 'val2'")


But I have found that it should be possible to register custom functions which would work in SpEL expression, which would be more neat, especially if condition will get more complicated.
What is the best solution to use in such scenario?
First I checked possibility to add logic to @ConditionalOnProperty, but after reading some answers here moved to @ConditionalOnExpression.
Then I have tried to add
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();

context.registerFunction(...);

and finally I have registered BeanFactoryPostProcessor as in https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/7df3f04d3be7acea5dfa
with
public interface CustomSpelFunctions {

        static boolean isIntegrationEnabled(@Value("${some.property}") String mode) {
            return ...
        }
    }

but as far as I can see beans get created before I can register anything, when I try to use
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{isIntegrationEnabled()}")

I get errors like this or similar:
EL1004E: Method call: Method isIntegrationEnabled() cannot be found on type org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext
What I am doing wrong? Is it possible to use custom function there? Or the only solution is to type condition directly in @ConditionalOnExpression annotation
I moved from non-spring to spring java quite recently and this is new for me.
We are using  spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.13, java 11
Edit:
trying solution from first answer (but using IntegrationContextUtils.getEvaluationContex(beanFactory) as I did not find it on https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanExpressionResolver.html) I got error
EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
so I tried to add extra ' around expression as in SpEL parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in expression (although method returns boolean and not String) and I got property value in logged error
@ConditionalOnExpression("'@isIntegrationEnabled('${some.property}')'")

"EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'VALUE_READ_FROM_PROPERTIES' " which I understand happens when evaluating argument for isIntegrationEnabled
Edit2:
I have noticed that
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor spelFunctionPostProcessor() {
    return (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) -> {
        //            StandardEvaluationContext context = (StandardEvaluationContext) beanFactory.getBeanExpressionResolver()
        //                .getEvaluationContext(beanFactory, null);
        StandardEvaluationContext context = IntegrationContextUtils.getEvaluationContext(beanFactory);

returns null when try to I build app without this expression in annotation
Edit3: I've checked Spring 3.4.1 with Java 17 and there is no  .getEvaluationContext on .getBeanExpressionResolver as well

Here is the solution shown below
Custom SpEL functions can help you solve your issue
1 ) Define a static method that will serve as your custom SpEL function
public class CustomSpelFunctions {
    
    public static boolean isIntegrationEnabled(String propertyValue) {
        return "val1".equals(propertyValue) || "val2".equals(propertyValue);
    }
}

2 ) Register this Custom Function in a BeanFactoryPostProcessor
@Configuration
public class SpelFunctionConfig {

    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor spelFunctionPostProcessor() {
        return (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) -> {
            StandardEvaluationContext context = (StandardEvaluationContext) beanFactory
                .getBeanExpressionResolver()
                .getEvaluationContext(beanFactory, null);

            try {
                context.registerFunction("isIntegrationEnabled",
                    CustomSpelFunctions.class.getDeclaredMethod("isIntegrationEnabled", String.class));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to register SpEL function", e);
            }
        };
    }
}

3 ) Use it through @ConditionalOnExpression
@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("@isIntegrationEnabled('${some.property}')")
public class CustomComponent {

}


Thanks, I forgot to add that we are using Java 11 so static methods on inner classes are not allowed. But  this is not a problem. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanExpressionResolver.html does not have getEvaluationContext, so I have used IntegrationContextUtils.getEvaluationContext but I still get error:  EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'
